# Opening .ppsm also opens powerpoint editor

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a macro within a PowerPoint slideshow which upon activating it should open a random .ppsm slideshow. It does this correctly but for some reason it not only opens the slideshow but it also opens it in the PowerPoint editor, which I don't need it to do.
When doing so in Powerpoint 2016 it displays the slides of that slideshow within the editor, in Powerpoint 2010 (which is the version I need it to work in the most) it only opens a blank copy of the editor.
Is there any way to prevent this window from opening?

This is the sub I am using:

```
Public Sub OpenROD()

Dim random_number As Integer

Randomize

random_number = Int(10 * Rnd) + 1

Presentations.Open FileName:="C:\Users\name\Desktop\NEW ROD\rod" & random_number & ".pps", _ 
ReadOnly:=True, WithWindow:=True

With ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself so posting it here in case someone has the same issue:

```
Public Sub OpenROD()

Dim Random_Number As Integer
Dim NewPres As Presentation

Randomize
Random_Number = Int(10 * Rnd) + 1

   Set NewPres = Presentations.Open(FileName:=("C:\Users\name\Desktop\NEW ROD\rod" & _
    Random_Number & ".pps"), WithWindow:=False)
   NewPres.SlideShowSettings.Run

End Sub
```